# overhead to unused "using" declarations?

Tags: c#, performance, using

I've just installed resharper and it's letting me know the namespaces i'm not actually using in each of my classes.

which lead me to the question - is there actually any overhead in leaving these, unused, using declarations in?

is it just a matter of tight code, or is there a performance hit in invoking these namespaces when i don't need to?

Comment: i was surprised i couldn't find it too.. feel free to close if it's a dup.

Comment: Duplicate: 
"Why removing unused usings in C#?" => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/629667/why-removing-unused-usings-in-c

Comment: @nailitdown: thank god, you added a "using" tag.  A question below yours was the one I was looking for when I searched by "tag"

Comment: no worries you can close it, i have my answer :)

Comment: I blame this all on SO search engine! ;)  "Using" is not a good keyword to search for...

Comment: use site:stackoverflow.com yoursearchtermhere On google.

Comment: How do you pursuade it to not stick in stuff you never asked for in the first place? (Grumble: typical VS - randomly throwing in code you never asked for and aren't ever going to use but will get blamed for if it breaks something ...)

Comment: @le dorfier - can you amend the default templates in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\ .... ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why should you remove unnecessary C# using directives?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136278/why-should-you-remove-unnecessary-c-using-directives)

Answer (score 100, accepted):

From [The C# Team's answers to frequently asked questions](http://blogs.msdn.com/csharpfaq/archive/2004/10/20/245411.aspx):

> When you add assembly references or
>   make use of the 'using' keyword,
>   **csc.exe will ignore any assembly which
>   you have not actually made use of in
>   your code** ... Don't [waste] your time stripping out
>   unused '`using`' statements or assembly
>   references from your application. **The
>   C# compiler will do so for you
>   automatically.**

You can verify that this is actually the case by calling `Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies()`; you'll see that anything that isn't used won't actually be included in the list.

The main utility in stripping out unused ones is

- It is easier to see what your code is actually using
- It will keep your Intellisense from being polluted with things that you aren't actually going to use.

Answer (score 41):

There are some performance reasons to strip down `using` statements:

- VS's IntelliSense runs faster when there is less data to look through

However, note all these reasons are compile-time specific.  The compiler strips unused `using`s automatically.

Comment: Note to anyone: feel free to add your own points.  This is a CW answer.  (I won't farm rep.  ;P)

Answer (score 11):

The biggest "overhead" in unusesd using statements is understanding your code :)

Removing unused ones makes your code tidier and easier for somebody else to read and maintain.

Answer (score 11):

The C# code editor in Visual Studio 2008 has a feature to remove unused **using** statements.

Right-click and select **Organize Usings | Remove Unused Usings**.

Comment: Thanks,Clearly Visual Studio 2008 and higher.