# Do Redundant Namespaces incur any overhead

Tags: .net, language-features

Other than maintenance complexity (and I would argue there is little to none), and the fact that it is not a clean solution (this I agree with) does importing redundant namespaces in a .NET class incur any overhead in terms of memory/space/etc.?

For instance, if I import My.Namespace but do not invoke *any* of its functionality, is the Visual Studio compiler smart enough not to package the corresponding binaries when my application is being deployed?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136278/why-should-you-remove-unnecessary-c-using-directives

Comment: Sorry, it appears I was using the wrong search phrase to find a similar post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [C# FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/csharpfaq/archive/2004/10/20/245411.aspx):

> When you add assembly references or
>   make use of the 'using' keyword,
>   csc.exe will ignore any assembly which
>   you have not actually made use of in
>   your code.

There are 2 related questions about this:

1. [Why should you remove unnecessary C# using directives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136278/why-should-you-remove-unnecessary-c-using-directives)
2. [overhead to unused “using” declarations ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641234/overhead-to-unused-using-declarations)

Answer (score 2):

There's no overhead for this, no. Note that the "My" namespace doesn't require you to deploy any extra binaries anyway - everything's in the Visual Basic assemblies shipped with the framework.