# What will happen if using namespace but not used in C#

Tags: c#, namespaces, using

I have a question. 
What will happen if using namespace but not used in C#.
Example:
**using System.Text;**
But I not use it.

Thank very much.
Tinhs

Comment: Does this make the program run slower or not?

Comment: An unused using has no impact to the runtime performance of your application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641234/overhead-to-unused-using-declarations