# Trying to increase speed

Tags: asp.net

I've been using things like Firebug and YSlow, so I'm not really looking for advice on increasing page load speeds, but I'm wondering does extra imports or using, especially if your importing or using classes that aren't necessary, cause a page to load slower?

Comment: Regarding the issue of unused using statements, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162766/how-is-performance-affected-by-an-unused-using-statement and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/629667/why-remove-unused-using-directives-in-c

Comment: Thank you Brandon, I did try to find that answer on my own, guess I didn't try hard enough.  That helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My opinion is Yes, because more server request cause more time for page to render.

Answer (score 1):

You're going about this the wrong way. Do your pages work yet? Get that done first. If they work, then are there specific performance problems with specific pages? Then address those specific problems. What you're doing is a waste of your time.

Comment: My pages do work, I've just had some speed complaints, so I'm going back and trying to do what I can to improve page load speeds.  Was wondering if unused Import statements would hurt speed.

Comment: Then you need to address specific speed complaints, like: "when I go to this page, and change the dropdown, it takes too long for the page to come back". Otherwise, you're solving problems that may not exist.

Comment: Thanks John, I am addressing specific complaints, but I was also wondering if having unusesd Using or Imports actually cause anything additional to happen or in any way increase the page load time in general.  I didn't look hard enough, but it seems the answer was already available in another post.  Thanks again.