# What is the benefit of removing redundant imports in VB.net or using in C# file

Tags: .net, resharper

I have been using ReSharper for quite a long time and get used to solve a lot of problems by typing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. One of my colleague asked me about the real benefits and I couldn't say a word apart from that if you are not using it why import it.

Can someone explain what are the real benefits of removing redundant imports if there are eany?

Comment: By redundant you mean useless?

Comment: Think of it as cleaning your room or making your bed.

Comment: Been asked many times.  Please see this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136278/why-should-you-remove-unnecessary-c-using-directives

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Beside the fact that it cleans up your code, you can also minimize 'name clashes'.
For instance, when you have 2 types with the same name in different namespaces, and you do not use any type from one namespace ...  You then do not have to specify the namespace of the type when using it, it keeps your code cleaner.

Answer (score 4):

It removes redundancy, which is a good thing.
And its easy to get most of the needed using directives back, by pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> (with R#) or invoking the smart-tag by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> (without R#) on the class that needs it.

On the negative side, you might lose sight of available extension methods, especially when the `System.Linq` namespace import is removed.

Comment: just a note: Resharper will show the quicklist for adding System.Linq namespace if you start typing linq query expressions.

Answer (score 2):

It'll reduce the size of your source code (very slightly), but also improves code quality in my opinion. If you only include what you need, it makes the intent of the file that much clearer.

If you're including a library you don't need, and I'm reading your code, I might end up wasting time trying to figure out where you reference it or why it's used.

Answer (score 1):

If you import more than you need you run into a few issues:

- When you try to use a class, it is ambiguous which class you mean and you have to specify further to disambiguate
- Autocomplete suggests many things that you're unlikely to use (it typically does this anyway, but having extra usings just makes the problem worse).
- It's hard to tell which dependencies your class has just from looking at the using list.

Answer (score 0):

It is faster -- if you have a reference the compiler has to load the symbol tables.

Comment: The topicstarter is not talking about references to assemblies, he talks about importing/using namespaces that are not used.

Comment: Yes I know that.  How do you think compilers are able to resolve the names when you use the import statement.  The compiler goes and reads a symbol table for that namespace and places the names in the symbol table so it can resolve them.  I don't mind getting a -1 when wrong, but this is compiler writing 101.

Comment: Here you go @Frederik someone else who said the same thing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136278/why-should-you-remove-unnecessary-c-using-directives/136320#136320

Answer (score 0):

There are no runtime or compilation performance benefits, at all. It just makes for prettier code.

Comment: Wouldn't the compilation be slower if more symbols are loaded?

Comment: Perhaps, but only marginally so; the human eye would rarely be able to tell the difference. You'll have a lot more performance problems from loading referenced projects during compilation than from unnecessary using statements.