# Does adding extra namespaces slow down a webpage?

Tags: c#, asp.net, namespaces

Does including a large number of namespaces on a page has any affect on the performance of the page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Theres a similar question here: [Why should you remove unnecessary C# using directives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136278/why-should-you-remove-unnecessary-c-sharp-using-directives)

Check it out, it's very well answered.

Answer (score 2):

No nothing of this nature actually happens. Look at this  for more details

[Why should you remove unnecessary C# using directives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136278/why-should-you-remove-unnecessary-c-sharp-using-directives)