# Do redundant expressions, directives and qualifiers impact performance?

Tags: performance, resharper, redundancy

I'm working with somebody else's code right now and ReSharper is giving me a lot of warnings about redundant code, such as:

- Unused directives
- Array creation expressions (`new string[]{xxx,xxx,xxx}` instead of `{xxx,xxx,xxx}`)
- Explicit delegate creation (`new EventHandler(xxx)` instead of `xxx`)
- Qualifiers (`System.Windows.Forms.Form` instead of `Form` when directives are used)

There is a lot of code to work with, so I'm not sure if it's worth going through it all and removing all redundant code.

With that in mind, I wanted to ask if these are warnings that are only there to improve code style (for aesthetics) or do those pieces of code actually perform extra operations and impact performance a little?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends.

- [Unused using directives don't matter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14580606).
- Abbreviated array initializers I'm pretty sure compile to the same CIL
- Explicit delegate creation I'm not so sure, but I'd expect the same performance
- Unneeded qualifiers I'm very sure compile to the same CIL.

### However

The computer's time is in general *much less important* than **your** time, or the time of anyone else reading the code. Take a piece of code and replace all the `int`s with `System.Int32`s and it will take *longer to read* and *longer to understand*, and those are also important 'performance' metrics.

Programs must be written for people to read, and only incidentally for machines to execute, as a much cleverer person than me once wrote.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. I want to skip the cleaning of that code, but at the same time I wanted to know it for future reference (when I write my own code).