# Why is the C# using directive called a "directive" when it does not affect the compilation process?

Tags: c#, using-directives

**Question**

Why is the C# [using directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) called a **directive** when it does not affect the compilation process?

Is there a difference between the terms **directive** and **preprocessor directive** ([examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx))?

This question is about terminology.

**Elaboration**

There is a [using directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) and there is a [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx). I'm talking about the [using directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) here.

Wikipedia says that [directives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directive_%28programming%29) are instructions for the compiler which change the compilation process.

This Stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/136646/33311) says that the C# using directive does not change the compilation process in any way.

So, if the using directive doesn't change the compilation process, why is it still called a directive?

Comment: I think the wiki-article describes a different kind of `directive` as it says in the second sentence: `Directives are not part of the language proper – they are not part of the grammar, and may vary from compiler to compiler` but the `using-directive` IS part of the grammar so this is just a different context the word is used in

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer you link to states that removing *unused* `using` directives doesn't affect compilation *output*.

The using directives list the namespaces the compiler is allowed to implicitly reference in the generated code. Without the directive, you must fully qualify all names, so:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
...
var x = new Process();
```

instead of

```
var x = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
```

So it is a true *directive* in the sense that it changes how the compiler interprets your code.

A *Preprocessor Directive* is applied to change the source code *before* it is compiled.
Preprocessor Directives in C# are very limited. Unlike in C / C++ -- where you can entirely re-write the source code before it is compiled -- in C# you can turn blocks of code on and off, and change a few compiler flags. As far as I'm aware, they aren't applied in a separate stage as in C / C++.

And for completeness, the `using` statement is syntactic sugar, turning

```
using (var x = new IDisposable()) {}
```

(where `var x =` is optional)

into

```
var x = new IDisposable();
try{ ... } 
finally { x.Dispose(); }
```