# Is it possible to create a shortcut for removing unused usings into a class?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I usually try to clean my code of unused using and the reason could be answered by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136278/why-should-you-remove-unnecessary-c-sharp-using-directives) post.

Whenever I want to do it, I have to use my mouse and it could be a bit annoying so that's the reason why I thought in a shortcut in order achieve it.
e.g:

[image]

And that's the result.

[image]

I couldn't find anything related that seems helpful.

Comment: ReSharper has such a short-cut, `Alt-Enter`, amazing to the point that you use it in other applications and wonder why it doesn't work, then lambaste them for not implementing it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the **Tools** menu, select **Options**, open the **Environment** folder, and choose **Keyboard**.

On the **Keyboard** page select a **Keyboard mapping scheme**.

In the **Show commands containing** text box, type `Edit.RemoveUnusedUsings`

In the scrolling list box, select the command you want the shortcut to execute.
On the Use new shortcut in drop-down list, select the environment in which you want to use the shortcut. Choose Global if you want the shortcut to work in all contexts.

Place your cursor in the Press shortcut key(s) text box and then press and hold a non-text key or combination of non-text keys (Alt, Ctrl, or Shift, for example) and type the text key of your choice.
Choose Assign.

[source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa301747(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: Slightly cheaper than ReSharper :-)

Comment: Excellent Robin!! I will select this as the answer. Very fast and self explained!

Comment: @Adam you never know if it is cheaper than resharper as you just lost some time that could have been used to develop stuff for $$ instead !!

Answer (score 3):

Tools > Option, navigate to Keyboard tab. Search for "Edit.RemoveAndSort" which command will to both remove unused usings and sort the usings, then set your shortcut