# Using Nullable<int> vs int? from a compilation performance point-of-view in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, types, compilation, nullable

I understand, from looking through previous questions on the topic, that `Nullable<int>` and `int?` get compiled to the same CIL. But it was pointed out that since Nullable needed the `using System` directive, it would make compilation as well as Intellisense slower if using `int?` made the `using System` directive unnecessary.

So my question is this:

> Does the compiler (using C# 6.0 on .NET 4.6.1 on Visual Studio Professional 2015) work harder to produce CIL code when it interprets `Nullable<int>` vs `int?` ?

Comment: I think that'll be roughly proportional to the difference between `int` and `Int32`.

Comment: @Ed Is there any way to quantify your answer?

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to be funny. They're synonymous.

Comment: Why do you think compilation and intellisense are slower when the `using System;` directive is present?

Comment: @D Stanley See Pop Catalin's answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136278/why-should-you-remove-unnecessary-c-sharp-using-directives?noredirect=1&lq=1