# Why can't I use partial root namespace?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a compiled class library with a root namespace `Protege.MyLibrary`.

It has a few root types, for example, `CommonlyNamedType`.

When I add the library to my consuming application, I'd like, for clarity in some situations, to be able to specify variables as:

```
using Protege;
...
MyLibrary.CommonlyNamedType oMyType = new MyLibrary.CommonlyNamedType;
```

rather than

```
using Protege.MyLibrary;
...
CommonlyNamedType oMyType = new CommonlyNamedType;
```

The former doesn't compile, indicating for the namespace `Protege` "Using directive is unnecessary", and that is can be removed.

This seems bizarre as I could go the other way and add additional namespaces, such as `Protege.MyLibrary.AnotherNamespace`.

I seem to be able to do this 100% okay in VB.NET - using either or both `Imports Protege` and/or `Protege.MyLibrary` and even optionally qualifying types with redundancy. But not in C#.NET.

I have had a good look around SO and other places and haven't seen an explanation for this behavior. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, it would make code cleaner in some cases. But it looks, that a namespace can exist on its own only it it has actual types in it.

Comment: "Using directive is unnecessary" is [warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48402517/what-makes-a-using-directive-unnecessary) and you can disable it if you really want... But as Eric Lippert pointed out in linked question there is a good chance you actually ending up with different type... It may be good idea to provide [MCVE] (you don't need separate libraries to show that - you can do that with just two files)

Comment: @ZorgoZ Nice observation. I hadn't thought of that. Weird that it doesn't trouble (lowly, unloved) VB in the least.

Comment: It's not that there's some insurmountable technical challenge. It's just two different languages with two sets of design goals that lead to different prioritisations.

Comment: @ZorgoZ Update: I checked this. I made the root namespace just `MyCompany` and added `Namespace = MyLibrary` to all of the code files then added a public `Enum Dummy ...` under the `MyCompany` namespace. Although the assembly shows `Dummy` under `MyCompany`, and I can just import `MyCompany` and use `MyCompany.Dummy`, I still can't use MyLibrary.CommonlyNamedType. So I'm still a bit clueless here.

Answer (score 0):

You can statically import a class like

```
using static System.IO.File;
```

It doesn't support for class, you need to use normal `using` for import the namespace.