# What is the purpose of Using?

Tags: .net, using-statement

**DUPE: [Uses of "using" in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75401/uses-of-using-in-c)**

I have seen people use the following and I am wondering what is its purpose?
Is it so the object is destroyed after its use by garbage collection?

Example:

```
using (Something mySomething = new Something()) {
  mySomething.someProp = "Hey";
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75401/uses-of-using-in-c

Comment: It's also found with a simple google search and in MSDN documentation.

Comment: @Charles: And GIYF answers are not at all welcome here.

Comment: I agree with rich, we don't allow for that IRC elitism attitude.  Any question is ok, except this is a dupe.

Comment: @Simucal, @Rich B - After re-reading my comment I can understand how it's being misread. I was sincere in my comment.

Answer (score 6):

Using translates, roughly, to:

```
Something mySomething = new Something();
try
{
  something.someProp = "Hey";
}
finally
{
  if(mySomething != null)
  {
    mySomething.Dispose();
  }
}
```

And that's pretty much it. The purpose is to support deterministic disposal, something that C# does not have because it's a garbage collected language. The using / Disposal patterns give programmers a way to specify exactly when a type cleans up its resources.

Comment: @Randolpho, Not quite. The object is instantiated outside of the try...finally block. If the object fails to instantiate then it can't/doesn't need to be disposed.

Comment: @Randolpho, And the generated IL will also check that the object isn't null before attempting to call Dispose.

Comment: Good points, Luke. I did preface with "roughly", remember.;)

Comment: @Randolpho, I wasn't trying to be picky, I just thought I'd point it out because yours is currently the top rated answer, so a lot of people might end up reading it. :)

Comment: Well, I've corrected it. I was more interested in explaining the purpose and context with my post, though, as that's frequently lost on folks.

Answer (score 4):

The using statement ensures that Dispose() is called even if an exception occurs while you are calling methods on the object.

Answer (score 2):

The using statement has the beneficial effect of disposing whatever is in the () when you complete the using block.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) when the `Something` class implements [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx). It ensures that the object is disposed correctly even if you hit an exception inside the `using` block.

ie, You don't have to manually handle potential exceptions just to call `Dispose`, the `using` block will do it for you automatically.

It is equivalent to this:

```
Something mySomething = new Something();
try
{
   // this is what's inside your using block
}
finally
{
    if (mySomething != null)
    {
        mySomething.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using gets translated into

```
try
{
   ...
}
finally
{
   myObj.Dispose();
}
```

when compiling (so in IL).

So basically you should use it with every object that implements `IDisposable`.

Answer (score 0):

The 'using' block is a way to guarantee the 'dispose' method of an object is called when exiting the block.

It's useful because you might exit that block normally, because of breaks, because you returned, or because of an exception.

You can do the same thing with 'try/finally', but 'using' makes it clearer what you mean and doesn't require a variable declared outside th block.