# What does using(object obj = new Object()) mean?

Tags: c#, .net, using-statement

What does this statement means in C#?

```
        using (object obj = new object())
        {
            //random stuff
        }
```

Comment: For your future reference, this is documented in section 8.13 of the C# specification.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the uses of "using" in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75401/what-are-the-uses-of-using-in-c)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It means that `obj` implements `IDisposible` and will be properly disposed of after the `using` block. It's functionally the same as:

```
{
  //Assumes SomeObject implements IDisposable
  SomeObject obj = new SomeObject();
  try
  {
    // Do more stuff here.       
  }
  finally
  { 
    if (obj != null)
    {
      ((IDisposable)obj).Dispose();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Almost right, using() doesn't imply a catch statement, only try/finally.

Comment: @Jay Zeng, as in Graphics? If i use my Graphics inside a "using" statement i wont need to dispose?

Comment: And the compiler inserts a check to ensure that the value is not null if the variable is of a nullable type.

Comment: No one mentioned that it also "touches" the object at the close brace by calling the .Dispose method.  This means that the garbage collector will not touch to object till after the .Dispose()

Answer (score 5):

```
using (object obj = new object())
{
    //random stuff
}
```

Is equivalent to:

```
object obj = new object();
try 
{
    // random stuff
}
finally {
   ((IDisposable)obj).Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Almost equivalent. In the first sample obj is out of scope at the }.  In the second, it is still in scope.  Similar to the for-while equivalence.

Answer (score 1):

why does it exist tho.

It exists for classes where you care about their lifetime, in particular where the class wraps a resource in the OS and you want to release it immediately. Otherwise you would have to wait for the CLR's (non deterministic) finalizers.

Examples, file handles, DB connections, socket connections, ....

Comment: i disagree - it is a well known pattern and so encourages common good practice. 

for loop is syntactical sugar too - but it is always used becuase it is a common idiom

also I was trying to explain why you see it used - and why you would see the non sugar version

Answer (score 0):

it is a way to scope an object so the dispose method is called on exit. It is very useful for database connections in particuler. a compile time error will occur if the object does not implement idisposable

Answer (score 0):

`using` ensures the allocated object is properly disposed after the using  block, even when an unhandled exception occurs in the block.