# What do DateTime? and using(var x = new y()) mean?

Tags: c#

I don't understand what the following lines mean, please explain them to me.

1.

```
DateTime? pInsertDate;
```

At this variable declaration, What does `?` mean?

2.

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
```

At this object creation, What does `using` mean?

Comment: Take a look at this question regarding `using`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75401/uses-of-using-in-c

Comment: You are asking two separate questions that both already have been answered for many times here at Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 6):

1. The `?` suffix is syntactic sugar for using `Nullable<T>`. So your declaration is equivalent to:

   ```
   Nullable<DateTime> pInsertDate;
   ```

   See the MSDN documentation for [nullable value types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for more information. Basically a nullable value type value can represent any of the values of the non-nullable underlying type (`DateTime` in this case) as well as the special "null" value. This *isn't* a null reference, but it's usually used with the same sort of connotations - "no value". For example, a Person class might have a `DateTime DateOfBirth` property, but a `DateTime? DateOfDeath` property, which would be null if the person was still alive.
2. A `using` statement is a way of automatically calling `Dispose` on the reference acquired in the first part of the statement at the end of the body. So your code is broadly equivalent to:

   ```
   TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope();
   try
   {
       // Body of the using statement
   }
   finally
   {
       if (scope != null)
       {
           scope.Dispose();
       }
   }
   ```

   In this case of course we know that`scope` *won't* be null because we're calling a constructor, but that's the general expansion. (You could have used a method call to obtain the transaction scope, for example - in which case it could have returned null, but the generated code won't throw a `NullReferenceException`.)

Comment: Jon, I need to ask you something. Is there any way to make an object nullable? I know that the objects are reference types and will be null if not referenced but my question is, is it possible to write myCustomObject? _temp = new myCustomObject() and assign the object to null on ctor if a condition is met?

Comment: @Pabuc: I think you're asking whether a constructor can return null - and the answer is no. Write a static method instead which either returns a reference to a new object or null.

Comment: So you can never write myCustomObject? _temp = new myCustomObject(); :/

Comment: @Pabus: Not if `MyCustomObject` is a reference type. What would that even mean? It's already a nullable type, just not a nullable *reference* type... you can already test whether the current value is null, etc.

Comment: (constructor returning null) well, *it can* - both for structs (`T?`), and classes - but only in evil cases ;p

Answer (score 1):

this is syntax for [Nullable Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

`SomeType?` is syntactic sugar for `Nullable<SomeType>`. It can only be applied to value types (not reference types) and indicates that the variable will also be able to store a value equivalent to what `null` is for reference types.  (Value types cannot be null, so the `Nullable<T>` type was added to allow for such cases.  It's extremely useful in database binding code, where nullable columns are common.)

`using (SomeType x = y) { ... }` is syntactic sugar for:

```
SomeType x = y;
try {
    ...
} finally {
    if (x != null)
        ((IDisposable)x).Dispose();
}
```

This pattern is common when using objects whose classes implement IDisposable, as a way to automatically clean up such objects when they are about to fall out of use.