# Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

**Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.**

whenever i load my project on explorer sometime i meet with an error.
can any1 help me to solve this time out error

Comment: Don't forget to close your connections.

Answer (score 2):

This usually happens when connections are not closed after they are used. Are you using a DataReader? If so make sure it is closed.

Comment: yes m using datareader bt after they are used i closed the connection.

Comment: What is your connect_timeout number?

Comment: i had set connection timeout=200 and pool size=100

Comment: now i had dispose all the command, reader, adapter, connection.

Comment: Future readers: Be sure to see [What are the uses of "using" in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75401/what-are-the-uses-of-using-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

This exception can also arise when same SQL query string is run over and over again several times e.g. inside a loop.

For a work-around try modifying connection string that is used in web service with the attributes like Connect Timeout , Max Pool Size.

> "Integrated Security=True;Server=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Connect Timeout=20000; pooling='true'; Max Pool Size=20000"