# Assignment in using directive

Tags: c#, episerver-6-r2

I just found the following code and don't know why it is done this way. Risk for conflict?

```
using DiffTreeNode = EPiServer.Enterprise.Diff.TreeNode;
```

And then in the class it is used as usual.

Why would you do something like this?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75401/uses-of-using-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a `using` *directive* (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx)) rather than a `using` statement and very similar to something like `using System.Text;`.

---

A `using` *statement* allows you to automatically clean up stuff without mucking about with `try/catch/finally` blocks:

```
using (Sometype xyzzy = new SomeType()) {
    // Do whatever with xyzzy
}
// xyzzy is gone, pining for the fjords.
```

---

The `using` *directive* imports a namespace so that you don't have to explicitly use the namespace to prefix all the types within it. Your particular variant basically creates an *alias* for the `EPiServer.Enterprise.Diff.TreeNode` namespace so you can simply refer to it as `DiffTreeNode` beyond that point. In other words, after the directive:

```
using DiffTreeNode = EPiServer.Enterprise.Diff.TreeNode;
```

the following two statements are equivalent:

```
EPiServer.Enterprise.Diff.TreeNode.SomeType xyzzy =
    new EPiServer.Enterprise.Diff.TreeNode.SomeType();
DiffTreeNode.SomeType xyzzy = new DiffTreeNode.SomeType();
```

and I know which I'd prefer to type in.

---

Now you may be asking why, if the directive can let you use the types within a namespace on their own, why do we not just do:

```
using EPiServer.Enterprise.Diff.TreeNode;
SomeType xyzzy = new SomeType();
```

My bet would be, though I'll wait for the likes of Jon Skeet to confirm or deny this :-), that it's to cover the case where you have two or more namespaces with identically named types. That would allow:

```
using Bt = Trees.BinaryTree;       // Has Tree type.
using Rbt = Trees.RedBlackTree;    // Annoyingly, also has Tree type.
Tree t = new Tree();               // Is this binary or redbalck?
Bt.Tree t1 = new Bt.Tree();        // Definite type.
Rbt.Tree t2 = new Rbt.Tree();      // Ditto.
```

Comment: Yes, I personally use it if you have a Tree in two namespaces.