# Why do we not need to return a value outside of the `using` scope?

Tags: c#

Consider this code:

```
public int DownloadSoundFile()
{
   using (var x= new X())
   {
       return x.Value;
   }
}
```

and this code:

```
public int DownloadSoundFile()
{
    if (x!=null)
    {
       return x.Value;
    }
}
```

The first code doesn't give us any compile time errors but in the second code we get this error:

> *not all code paths return a value*

This means we should return a value outside of the `if` scope.

Why do we have to return a value outside of the `if` scope but don't need to return a value outside of the `using` scope?

Comment: In this context `using (...) { return ...; }` is the same as `{ return ...; }`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> why we should return value out of the if scope but don't need return
>   value out of the using Scope?

Because the `if` scope might not execute (if the condition is not satisfied) whereas the body of the `using` scope is guaranteed to always execute (it will either return the result or throw an exception which is acceptable for the compiler). For the `if` scope your method is undefined if the condition is not satisfied and the compiler refuses that.

So you should decide what value to return if the condition you wrote is not satisfied:

```
public int DownloadSoundFile()
{
    if (x != null)
    {
       return x.Value;
    }

    // at this stage you should return some default value
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But whay we should in using

Comment: You should use `using` when you are dealing with `IDisposable` instances. It will ensure that the Dispose method will be always invoked.

Comment: @ShahroozJefriㇱ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75401/uses-of-using-in-c-sharp

Comment: @ShahroozJefriㇱ You don't have to `return` from within a `using` block. You can very well call `return` when you're outside of the `using` block. Also, you don't *have to* `return` from outside an `if` block. If you `return` from within an `if` block, then you *must* also `return` from within an `else` block.

Comment: @ShahroozJefri, `return` returns from a method not from all blocks. A using block is not a method, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h3swy84(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @FSou1, that's generally why we +1, yes :P

Comment: @Moo-Juice yeap ^.^ but sometimes, i have a strange feeling to tell about it

Answer (score 7):

> so we should return value out of the if scope.

No. You should return a value from an `int method()`. It has nothing to do with `if()` vs `using()`.

```
public int DownloadSoundFile()
{
    if (x!=null)
    {
        return x.Value;
    }
    // and now?? no return value for the method
    // this is a 'code path that does not return a value'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int DownloadSoundFile()
{
    if (x!=null)
    {
        return x.Value;
    }
}
```

In this code what if **x** is `null`!!! In this condition how the function will return the value. So the correct code would be.

```
public int DownloadSoundFile()
{
    if (x!=null)
    {
        return x.Value;
    }
    else
    {
        // your return statement;
    }
}
```

You can also use below code.

```
return x != null ? x.value : *something else*
```

*Using is not used to return something, it is mainly used so that code will not break because of exception. Mainly database connections are created in using statement. Because this makes sure that connections exceptions are suppressed and connection is closed once it goes out of scope.Generally objects inherited from IDisposable are used inside using statement so that dispose() method will be called.*

Comment: What is wrong if we use ?: operator in this manner. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ty67wk28(v=VS.80).aspx. return  statements are also expressions so we can use them inside ?:

Comment: From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28(v=vs.80).aspx): `The conditional operator (?:) returns one of two values depending on the value of a Boolean expression.` This means `condition ? first_statement : second_statement` is invalid.

Comment: Yes yes got it. My bad.

Comment: You misunderstood the question. Shahrooz was asking why the code below the using statement doesn't require a return value, as it looked like another code path.

Comment: To be clear for future readers: _Expression_ is something that evaluates to value; _Statement_ is line of code that does something.

Answer (score 0):

`using` is an alias for following code :

```
IDisposable x = null;
try
{
     x= new X();
     //inside the using
     return x.Value;
}
finally
{
     if(x != null)
        x.Dispose();
}
```

So you can notice that every path return a value; in fact, there is only ONE path (or maybe an expeption).