# Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement. System.Data.OleDb.OleDbErrorCollection

Tags: asp.net, database, webforms, ms-access-2010

Hi I am creating basic form in Visual Studio 2012 Express. I am using Microsoft Access 2012 as database. My problem is when I press submit button I nothing happens.

> Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbErrorCollection

My code is given below. Please help me to resolve this issue.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string conString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\admin\Desktop\del\SHAFI\db.accdb";
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conString);
    OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    string text = "INSERT INTO TEST (Number, Amount) VALUES (?, ?)";
    cmd.CommandText = text;
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Number", txtAmount.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Amount", txtOrder.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (OleDbException ex)
    {
        txtAmount.Text = "Sorry";
        Response.Write(ex.Message.ToString() + "<br />" + ex.Errors.GetType());
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is you are using Number which is clearly a reserved word.

Try to either change it or wrap it around [] as in [Number] and see what happens now.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is correct, apart from the lacking of [using statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75401/uses-of-using-in-c-sharp) around disposable objects, but the real problem is the word NUMBER. It is a [reserved keyword for MSAccess](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321266).
Use it enclosed in square brackets.

```
string text = "INSERT INTO TEST ([Number], Amount) VALUES (?, ?)";
```

However, if it is still possible, I really suggest you to change that column name. This problem will become very annoying.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string conString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\admin\Desktop\del\SHAFI\db.accdb";
    using(OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conString))
    using(OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
    {
        string text = "INSERT INTO TEST ([Number], Amount) VALUES (?, ?)";
        cmd.CommandText = text;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Number", txtAmount.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Amount", txtOrder.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (OleDbException ex)
        {
            txtAmount.Text = "Sorry";
            Response.Write(ex.Message.ToString() + "<br />" + ex.Errors.GetType());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`OleDbCommand` does not support named parameters. You have to add the parameters in the order you want them.

```
//Code above
con.Open();
cmd.Parameters.Add(txtAmount.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add(txtOrder.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
//Code below
```

Comment: I changed my code and now getting this error.No overload for method 'AddWithValue' takes 1 arguments C:\Users\admin\Desktop\del\SHAFI\excel-database\excel-database\Test.aspx.cs

Comment: Look at my update. I forgot to update the method call to use `Add` instead of `AddWithValue`.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `@Number` and `@Amount` variables for `Number` and `Amount` but not writing these values in query.

`?` used in java not in asp.net(c#). so you are mixing these two.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string conString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\admin\Desktop\del\SHAFI\db.accdb";
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conString);
    OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    string text = "INSERT INTO TEST (Number, Amount) VALUES (@Number, @Amount)";
    cmd.CommandText = text;
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Number", txtAmount.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Amount", txtOrder.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (OleDbException ex)
    {
        txtAmount.Text = "Sorry";
        Response.Write(ex.Message.ToString() + "<br />" + ex.Errors.GetType());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
string text = "INSERT INTO TEST (Number, Amount) VALUES (@Number, @Amount)";
```

instead of:

```
INSERT INTO TEST (Number, Amount) VALUES (?, ?)
```