# Is my logic correct? I'm trying to get data from combobox(dropdownlist) and use that data to search and display information in checkedlistbox

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, search, combobox

I keep getting this error whenever I do the search:  Invalid column name 'datafromcombobox'

I tried hardcode the data in my SQL query and it works.  Any idea what's wrong with my code?

Here's the code:

```
        string selectedMedication = cboMedicationType.SelectedItem.ToString();

        string strMedications = "SELECT medicationName FROM MEDICATION WHERE medicationType= (" + selectedMedication + ")";
        SqlCommand cmdMedications = new SqlCommand(strMedications, connection);

        connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader readMedications = cmdMedications.ExecuteReader();

        while (readMedications.Read())
        {
            string medicationVar = readMedications["medicationName"].ToString();
            clbMedication.Items.Add(medicationVar, true);

        }
        readMedications.Close();
        connection.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just forgot the quotes in your query.
This should work :

```
string strMedications = "SELECT medicationName FROM MEDICATION WHERE medicationType=   ('" + selectedMedication + "')";
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```
using (SqlCommand cmdMedications = new SqlCommand(strMedications, connection))
{
    string strMedications = "SELECT medicationName FROM MEDICATION WHERE medicationType = @selectedMedication;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("selectedMedication", cboMedicationType.SelectedItem.ToString());
    connection.Open();
    using (SqlDataReader readMedications = cmdMedications.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (readMedications.Read())
        {
            string medicationVar = readMedications["medicationName"].ToString();
            clbMedication.Items.Add(medicationVar, true);
        }
    }
    connection.Close();
}
```

I changed several things:

- **Always** use parameterized queries. If you don't, you can be a victim of [SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/using-parameters-in-sql-statements). I changed that in your code.
- It's usually better to use `using` in your code ([see this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75401/uses-of-using-in-c-sharp)), because then you don't need to `close` or `dispose` objects--the `using` statements take care of that.
- As for your error, it's probably an error in your query, but my code should take care of that.

Let me know if I can clear up something else. I hope this helps!

P.S. I mostly typed this without debugging so there might be some small things you might have to tweak, but I thing you should get the gist of it.