# SQL Connection constructor outside the using statement

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sqlconnection

I have the following code:

```
SqlConnection Connect = new SqlConnection(IST_DBConnect.SQLConnectionString);
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlCommandString, Connect);
RequestRow Result = new RequestRow();
Connect.Open();
using (Connect)
...
```

This is not my code, I would write the creation of the SQL Connection in a using statement, this is a code of my friend, I am no exactly sure if this is going to dispose properly the SQL connection object if something goes wrong in the constructor or in the Open method. So my question is if the connection object is created and the open method throws an exception => the connection is never opened, will this be disposed properly?

Thanks.

Comment: Go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75401/uses-of-using-in-c-sharp

Comment: The `using` statements internally implement `finally` block, and even in case of an exception, it make sure that the object is `disposed` properly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx);

> As a rule, when you use an IDisposable object, you should **declare** and
>   **instantiate** it **in** a using statement.

and

> You can instantiate the resource object and then pass the variable to
>   the using statement, **but this is not a best practice**. In this case,
>   the object remains in scope after control leaves the using block even
>   though it will probably no longer have access to its unmanaged
>   resources. In other words, it will no longer be fully initialized. **If
>   you try to use the object outside the using block, you risk causing an
>   exception to be thrown. For this reason, it is generally better to
>   instantiate the object in the using statement and limit its scope to
>   the using block.**

Based on your example, if somethings goes wrong in constructor, of `Open` method, there is nothing `using` *can* do since you use it as a resource *after* you initialize it.

Sure this is the best way;

```
using(var Connect = new SqlConnection(IST_DBConnect.SQLConnectionString))
using(var command = Connect.CreateCommand())
{
   // 
} // <-- Both Connect and command will disposed here no matter exception is thrown or not
```