# SqlConnection and SqlCommand programming pattern: which one is better?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

```
private void a()
{

    string query = "";

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connectionstring here"))
    {
        conn.Open();

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
        {
            cmd.ExecuteQuery();
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
}

private void B()
{

    string query = "";
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connectionstring here");

    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
    cmd.ExecuteQuery();

    conn.Close();
}
```

Which of the two is better to use? and why?

Comment: Can you please show your code as a plain text instead of image? And "better" is kind of subjective. It would be better to ask if you have a _specific_ problem.

Comment: First one since it's using `using`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75401/uses-of-using-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2):

The first version is better, because you don't have to remember to `Close` the connection, since `SqlConnection` is wrapped in a using statement. The `conn.Close()` call in the first version is not needed. The connection will be closed in the `finally` block of the `using`.

Comment: `SqlCommand` *does* implement `IDisposable`, as it derives from `Component`. The code wouldn't even compile otherwise. So yes, I would keep the `using` statement for that.

Comment: @JonSkeet I wasn't aware of this :(. I will correct my answer. Thanks

Comment: I kind of disagree with your _there isn't any need of using a using for the SqlCommand object_ sentence.  `SqlCommand` _indirectly_ inherits from `Component` which implements a finalizer.

Comment: An additional benefit of the `using` statement is that the object will be disposed of once the `using` block is exited - which means even if an exception is thrown, your connection will still be disposed.  That is not the case in your second example.

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb:

- Always dispose `IDisposable`s.
- It is easiest to do it with `using`.

So ...