# Why do we need IDisposable objects?

Tags: c#, .net

I come from a C++ background and have trouble understanding the point of `IDisposable` objects (and the point of many other things in .NET). Why is a `Dispose` function necessary in the first place? Whatever it does, why not do that in the destructor of the class? I understand it cleans up managed resources, but isn't that what a destructor is supposed to do? I understand that

```
Using ( var obj = new SomeIDisposableObject ) 
{
    // ...
}
```

is the equivalent of

```
var obj = new SomeIDisposableObject;
// ...
obj.Dispose();
```

but how does that save any typing? And if C# has a garbage collector, which it does, then why are we ever worried about disposing resources?

Is `IDisposable`/`Using`/etc. a Skeet-approved concept? What does he think of it?

Comment: the `using` saves typing because it will dispose the object on every exit path, including exceptions.

Comment: "*I understand it cleans up managed resources*" -- Incorrect: it's the opposite. It cleans up *unmanaged* resources. Managed resources are, by definition, managed by the GC.

Comment: One should be cautious of invoking the Skeet without first determining that the question is worthy.

Comment: [John Saunders has a good comment about that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75401/uses-of-using-in-c-sharp#comment11016113_75483)

Comment: What is Skeet-approved concept? Should be aware of it before deploying code to production?

Comment: @AdrianIftode - [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)

Comment: @AdrianIftode I know that some concepts such as `dynamic` are not approved by Skeet

Comment: Duplicate is 100% as requested - Jon Skeet's explanation.

Answer (score 8):

`IDisposable` is nothing special. It's just an interface that makes you have a `Dispose()` function. `IDisposable` won't clear anything or destroy objects. A call to `Dispose()` does nothing if that function does nothing.

The use of `IDisposable` is a **pattern**. It's so important that it gets its own language construct (the `using` block), but it's just a pattern.

The difference with a destructor, is that in .NET, the destructor is non-deterministic. You never know when the garbage collector will collect your object. You don't even know if it even will (unlike using `delete` in C++, which is deterministic).

So `IDisposable` is there for *deterministically* releasing unneeded references (and releasing unmanaged resources). The "disposed" object will remain in memory after you call `Dispose` until the garbage collector decides to collect it (at which point, the "destructor" will be called, unless you explicitly tell it not-to), if it ever decides to.

That's the main difference to using "destructors" (or **finalizers**, as they are called in C#).

As for the *why* do we need it:

1. Managed references to other objects prevent objects to be collected by the garbage collector. So you need to "release" those references (by, for example, setting the variables that reference those objects to `null`).
2. Objects in .NET can use **unmanaged** resources, if they use native libraries. For example, every control or bitmap in a `Windows.Forms` application uses a `Win32 handler`, which is unmanaged. If you don't release those resources, you may reach the handle limit in Windows if using any big application, easily. Also, if you need interoperability with any non-.NET API, you'll more likely have to allocate unmanaged memory (with the use of, for example, `Marshal.AllocHGlobal`), which will need to be released at some point: that point is *generally* the `Dispose()` function of the `IDisposable`, which must be called explicitly (or by using a `using` block).

As for the `using` block, it's more equivalent to:

```
var myObject = new MyDisposableClass();
try
{
  ...
} 
finally {
  myObject.Dispose();
}
```

So it does indeed save typing

Answer (score 1):

Using a `using` block doesn't only call the `.Dispose` method; it calls the .Dispose method when you leave the block, however you leave it.  So, if your code crashes, it will still call Dispose.  The actual code would be closer to:

```
try
{
    var obj = new SomeIDisposableObject;
    // ...
}
catch (exception ex)
{
}
finally
{
    obj.Dispose();
}
```

Additionally, destructors don't always fire when you expect them to.  I've had a few bugs where the destructor is called after the program has apparently exited, and tried to access resources that no longer exist.  Since you don't `know` when it will be called, it's difficult to fix this.