# Is this a proper use of dispose

Tags: c#

Even with C#'s garbage collection, I feel I should release resources when done using them. Is this the proper use of dispose to release my ssh client?

```
            public void Disconnect()
            {
                string _disconnect = "bye";
                _sendCommand = _disconnect;
                SendToCodec(_sendCommand);
                client.Disconnect();
                client.Dispose();
            }
```

Comment: no. you better use `using` statement instead of calling dispose manually  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75401/uses-of-using-in-c-sharp

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary: That's only really doable when you only need your object in one method. It doesn't seem like that in this case.

Comment: The comment about using a `using` isn't helpful since clearly your `client` variable spans methods. The only suggestion I'd make is put the SendToCodec and Disconnect in a `try` and the `Dispose` in a `finally` to ensure it happens even if an exception is thrown.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen yes, that's correct, the client is spanning 40-60 methods...probably many more by the time I'm done. Thanks for the try...finally suggestion

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of `Dispose` and friends is to release unmanaged resources which are usually *other things than just memory* that may cause problems if they stay around until the garbage collector gets around to collecting the object. If the object behaves correctly the non-memory resources will be reclaimed eventually when the GC destroys the object, but that could be a long time later. As an example, a `FileStream` that is not properly disposed will leave the file open until it's eventually collected, which may prevent others from accessing the file.

As a rule of thumb, if the object in question has a `Dispose` method, it's usually a good indication you should call it when you're done with it.

Note that in the case of many object such as built-in file and socket objects, there's also an alternate method called something like `Close`. There is no need to call both `Dispose` and `Close` - in fact one will probably just call the other inside. (Example: `TcpClient.Close` really just calls `Dispose` inside)

Answer (score 1):

You should always call `Dispose()` or use a `using` statement which automatically calls `Dispose()` on an object that implements `IDisposable`. It never hurts and it's better to be safe than sorry. Not only that, but it makes your intention clear to whoever has to support your code after you.