# Including other files in Unity without the "using" statement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, using, using-statement

I have to integrate someone's code from a Unity project.

They created a file with the definition of a class that's an array of points, and another file that uses the first file's class.

Problem: I don't see any "using (nameOfTheFile)" at the beginning of the second file: how is this possible?
How can I use the first file in the second?

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41421472/how-to-include-multiple-classes-in-one-project-with-one-namespace-how-to-use-th) (I picked the wrong question in the dialog!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing the files in particular I can assume they are likely in the same namespace.

A class implicitly has access to everything in the same assembly under the same namespace as itself when they have `internal` or `public` visibility, so these two classes are likely in the same namespace and have access to one another.

```cs
// brain.cs
namespace Brain {
   public class A {
      public B InstanceOfB { get; set;}
   }
   public class B { }
}
```

This will still work if the two classes are in separate files, so the above is the same as:

```cs
/// brain.A.cs
namespace Brain {
   public class A {
      public B InstanceOfB { get; set;}
   }
}


/// brain.B.cs
namespace Brain {
   public class B { }
}
```

Ultimately you just need to add the using statement for the namespace they use in their code when adding the files to your project (`using Brain;` for the example above).

**Default Namespaces edit:**

Default namespaces are set for classes that don't specify this in the code file. You can find the default namespace (called `RootNamespace`) in the `*.csproj` files in a `<PropertyGroup>` in the `<Project>` element (usually it's the first PropertyGroup in the file):

```xml
<!-- Brain.Common.csproj -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  ...
  <PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <RootNamespace>Brain.Common</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Brain.Common</AssemblyName>
    ...
```

Comment: I'm sorry, namespace is not used and the files are too big to be written here. Do you think there's another method or keyword that I should be looking for?

Comment: There is a default namespace used in assemblies when it's not specified in your code, I've edited the answer to show you how to find them.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative might also be to use the [`partial`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods) keyword on a kind of super class and implement your classes as subclasses like e.g.

ScriptA.cs

```
public partial class SuperClass
{
    public class A { }
}
```

ScriptB.cs

```
public partial class SuperClass
{
    public class B 
    {
        public A = new A();
    }
}
```