# C# selenium SocketException when calling ChromeDriver.Navigate()?

Tags: c#, wpf, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, socketexception

It's not been a lot that I started using Selenium. I'm writing a WPF application that should automatically look for a book on this site and then represent the results on a ListView. Everything's fine at first, the problem comes up when I decide to search a second time. Every time a press the search button I call the Navigate().GoToUrl() method of WebDriver, and after the first time, if I press it again I get this:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'Unexpected error. System.Net.WebException: Impossible to connect with the remote server. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Impossible to estabilish a connection. Persistent refusal of the computer 127.0.0.1:52601

in System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)

in System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)

--- Fine della traccia dello stack dell'eccezione interna ---

in System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)

in System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()

in OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)

in OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
```

That's my MainWindow class, where everything is done:

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using System.Threading;

namespace MyLibrary
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Logica di interazione per MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Catalog catalog;
        List<Category> categories;
        XmlDocument catalogXml;
        string xmlPath;

        ChromeDriver resultFinder;
        Thread resultFinderThread;
        string searchName;

        struct ResultViewListItem
        {
            public string N { get; set; }
            public string Result { get; set; }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            LoadCatalog();
            LoadResultFinder();
        }

        private void LoadCatalog()
        {
            categories = new List<Category>();

            xmlPath = "C:/Users/Andrea Ferrando/Documents/Visual Studio 2017/Projects/Andrea/MyLibrary/MyLibrary/Catalog/catalog.xml";
            catalogXml = new XmlDocument();

            catalogXml.Load(xmlPath);

            foreach(XmlNode node in catalogXml.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
            {
                categories = getCategories(categories, node);
            }

            catalog = new Catalog(categories, catalogXml, xmlPath);
        }

        private List<Category> getCategories(List<Category> categories, XmlNode node)
        {
            int number = Int32.Parse(node.Attributes["number"].Value);
            string description = node.Attributes["description"].Value;

            Category category = new Category(number, description, categories);
            categories.Add(category);

            if(node.HasChildNodes)
            {
                foreach (XmlNode child in node.ChildNodes)
                {
                     category.Children = getCategories(category.Children, child);
                }

                return categories;
            }

            return categories;
        }

        private void LoadResultFinder()
        {
            ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            chromeOptions.AddArgument("--window-position=-32000,-32000");

            ChromeDriverService chromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
            chromeDriverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

            resultFinder = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, chromeOptions);

            searchName = "";
        }

        private void Grid_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.Source.Equals(FindName("Search")))
            {
                TextBox textBox = (TextBox)FindName("SearchBox");

                searchName = textBox.Text;

                resultFinderThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(findResults));
                resultFinderThread.Start();
            }
        }

        private void findResults()
        {
            using (resultFinder)
            {
                resultFinder.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.sbn.it/opacsbn/opac/iccu/free.jsp");

                IWebElement inputField = resultFinder.FindElementByName("item:1016:Any");
                inputField.SendKeys(searchName);

                IWebElement submitField = resultFinder.FindElementByName("Invia");
                submitField.Click();

                IWebElement table = resultFinder.FindElementById("records");
                IList<IWebElement> trElements = table.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));
                IList<IWebElement> tdElements;
                List<string> information = new List<string>();

                foreach (IWebElement trElement in trElements)
                {
                    tdElements = trElement.FindElements(By.TagName("td"));

                    information.Add(tdElements[2].Text);
                }

                Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    ListView listView = (ListView)FindName("ResultsList");

                    for (int i = 0; i < information.Count; i++)
                    {
                        listView.Items.Add(new ResultViewListItem { N = (i + 1).ToString(), Result = information[i] });
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The important method is **FindResults()**
I hope I've been clear enough, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess your connection is close somehow the second time you call it.

I guess also you are calling tow times the method `findResults()`.

The problem is that you are using the `using` statement. This statement disposes the connection once the code block is exited. In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75483/3866548) answer you can find more information about how it works.

You should not Dispose the object until you have finish using it. I would delete the `using` for starting, then I would use some other technique to dispose the object.

Hope this helps.