# What is the difference between the using statement and not storing a object

Tags: c#

How do these two different implementations effect performance or how objects are allocated in memory?

```
using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = AES.CreateEncryptor())
{
    byte[] cipherBytes = encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
}


byte[] cipherBytes = AES.CreateEncryptor().TransformFinalBlock(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
```

Comment: Please alter my title if you have a more precise wording

Comment: see IDisposable and GC.SuppressFinalize(this)

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy - The encryptor won't be disposed under any circumstances in the second example, regardless of whether an exception is thrown.

Comment: @Lee totally agree

Comment: The title, for me, sounds like: "What is the difference between a cat and not drinking beer". The two things are unrelated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever the object uses **unmanaged resources**, you need to dispose the resources, so that other programs can use that resource — *Windows cannot delete this file, as it is being used by another program*, that is an example of error you see when you do not release the resources being held by your program. Although there is a factor of slow performance — barely noticeable — in the `using` code of yours, but that is a better code provided it would also dispose any resources that your objects are *holding*. Nonetheless, it does create a variable, and that variable is what gets `.Dispose()` called.

In the second code, you would need to manually call `.Dispose()` function — but on what? You didn't store the variable at all. You can create the function, and the following code would *try* to mimic what is happening in the first block,

```
// Create and use.
var encryptor = AES.CreateEncryptor();
byte[] cipherBytes = encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);

// This function is called by "using" automatically.
encryptor.Dispose();
```

There are some other useful resources, for best practices in C# programming, I would recommend you give them a good thought and have a look at them. :)

[using Statement (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)
[Uses of `using` in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75401/uses-of-using-in-c-sharp)