# creating login form with entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I created a simple Login Form in C# with entity framework.
I keep getting this error in the if statement where it calls `query.SingleOrDefault`

```
Error   CS0103  The name 'Query' does not exist in the current context  rooster
```

im relatively new to this, how do i fix this error?

My Code:

```
    private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEmail.Text))
        {
            // check voor invoeren van wachtwoord en email.
            MessageBox.Show("Voer u email adres in!", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            txtEmail.Focus();
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            using (roosterAppEntities db = new roosterAppEntities())
            {
                var query = from u in db.Users
                            where u.username == txtEmail.Text && u.password == txtPassword.Text
                            select u;                                         
            }
            if (query.SingleOrDefault() != null)
           {
                MessageBox.Show("Succesvol ingelogd! ", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
           }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            throw;
        }


    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initializing the variable `query` inside a `USING()`. As soon as your code disposes your `db` context, `query`will be lost too. Please define it outside the using.

Here on SO is a very good question about the C# function of `USING`, [please take a look.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75401/uses-of-using-in-c-sharp)

Example:

```
    try
    {
        IQueryable query = null;
        using (roosterAppEntities db = new roosterAppEntities())
        {
            query = from u in db.Users
                        where u.username == txtEmail.Text && u.password == txtPassword.Text
                        select u;                                         
        }
        if (query.SingleOrDefault() != null)
       {
            MessageBox.Show("Succesvol ingelogd! ", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
       }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        throw;
    }
```