# Will using destroy data if return will be inside

Tags: c#, using

While working on my project, I was wondering, will using auto-destruct data if return will be inside of a using.

Example block of code:

```
using(ManagedObject obj = new ManagedObject()) 
{
    int usualNumber = 0;

    // some magic stuff
    ...
    // magic stuff ends

    return usualNumber; // return goes inside of 'using' brackets
}
```

And here is the question, will our ManagedObject which implements IDisposable be disposed by 'using' statement?

Comment: The *only* thing the [using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) does is call `Dispose` on the object being "used": and, it will do this in *all* cases (except abrupt program termination): leaving normally, exception thrown, return from inside... Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75401/what-are-the-uses-of-using-in-c-sharp which shows how it could be implemented with `try..finally`.

Comment: [using Statement(C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement)

Comment: @Plutonix That is the wrong concept. The using *statement* supports the Disposable pattern, the using *directive* imports type names into scope.

Comment: Fixed, clicked the wrong one

Comment: It doesn't "destroy" your data, it simply calls the object's.Dispose method. As others have mentioned, it just surrounds the block of code in a try/finally and calls Dispose in the finally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`using` is a Syntactic sugar, it need to contain an object which implements `IDisposable` interface when you leave the `using` scope .net will call the `IDisposable.Dispose` method Automatically.

Here is a sample [c# online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WqIWEX)

when the program leave `Test` method. `.net` will call `IDisposable.Dispose` method Automatically

Answer (score 1):

`using` statement can be seen as `try` and `finally` combination.

Your code is equivalent to:

```
ManagedObject obj = new ManagedObject();

try
{
  int usualNumber = 0;

  // some magic stuff
  ...
  // magic stuff ends

  return usualNumber;
}
finally
{
  if (obj != null)
    ((IDisposable)obj ).Dispose();
}
```

I assume, that the answer to your question can be seen thanks to this code sample.

Comment: Thank you for this variant, was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It will call the `Dispose()` function implemented by the `IDisposable` interface

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Test().TestIt();
        Console.Read();
    }
}

class Test
{
    public int TestIt()
    {
        using (ManagedObject obj = new ManagedObject())
        { 
            int usualNumber = 0;       
            return usualNumber;
        }
    }
}

internal class ManagedObject : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Disposed");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, even if you `return` from inside the using block, it will still call `Dispose` on `obj`.

Note that returning the `usualNumber` is perfectly fine, but if you were to return `obj`, that could be a problem because you would be returning a "disposed" object.

(Technically, objects could be usable after calling Dispose. For example, you could implement a Dispose that does nothing. But *generally*, most Dispose implementations would put the object in an unusable state).