# vjslib.dll zip file contains unicode file name as ????.xyz

Tags: c#, unicode

I have a problem with files with a **Unicode name** in Zip. I am using vjslib.dll. in a normal scenario, it's working perfect but when I am trying to zip file which has a Unicode character name like "**サンプルファイル.pdf**"it's represented as a "**???????.pdf**", in zip file while extracting a zip file Unicode file name nane represent as a "**_______.pdf**"
is there any way to generate a zip with the exact name of the file does not matter file name in English or another language

zipFileName = "c:\SampleZip\myfile.zip"

sourceFile

1. c:\sample\サンプルファイル.pdf
2. c:\sample\отличается.xml

   ```
   private void Zip(string zipFileName, string[] sourceFile)
   {
       FileOutputStream filOpStrm = new FileOutputStream(zipFileName);
       ZipOutputStream zipOpStrm = new ZipOutputStream(filOpStrm);
       FileInputStream filIpStrm = null;

       foreach (string strFilName in sourceFile)
       {
           filIpStrm = new FileInputStream(strFilName);
           ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry(Path.GetFileName(strFilName));
           zipOpStrm.putNextEntry(ze);
           sbyte[] buffer = new sbyte[1024];
           int len = 0;

           while ((len = filIpStrm.read(buffer)) >= 0)
           {
               zipOpStrm.write(buffer, 0, len);
           }
       }

       zipOpStrm.closeEntry();
       filIpStrm.close();
       zipOpStrm.close();
       filOpStrm.close();
   }
   ```

Comment: First, it is bad practice to use `Close()` with your streams the way you did here. Wrap the streams with `using` statements instead (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75401/what-are-the-uses-of-using-in-c-sharp). Second, i assume you use SharpZipLib. You should be able to enable Unicode support (more accurately UTF-8 support) for each ZipEntry individually by setting its `ZipEntry.IsUnicodeText` property to _true_.

Comment: vjslib.dll is old, being able to only use 8-bit encoding for names was an old .zip format restriction.  Lots of shiny new zip libraries around.