# 'using' keyword before local variable declaration in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, using

Hi I was going through some examples in C# and came across some code similar to below :

```
private void WriteData(string filePath)
{
    using var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filePath);

    //Logic to write data here
}
```

I want to know what is the use and significance of `using` in variable declaration.
Also how is it different from simple variable declaration :

```
var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filePath);
```

Comment: you might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75401/what-are-the-uses-of-using-in-c#

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen it's accepted answer shows the new style aswell

Comment: Ah, yes it does. Thank you, didn't notice that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a C# 8 syntax sugar for a traditional `using` statement which ensures that `Dispose()` method will be called for a type implementing `IDisposable` interface.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement#example