# You should not call Dispose more than one time on an object (CA2202)

Tags: c#, ca2202

I've seen posts on this question but I can't seem to get rid of the warning by following the examples here and other places online. Do you see what I am missing to avoid getting the `CA2202 Warning` that says:

> To avoid generating a System.ObjectDisposedException you should not call Dispose more than one time on an object.

I thought the using would dispose the `xmlReader`. Is it also disposing the `stringReader` ?

```
StringReader stringReader = null;
try
{
    stringReader = new StringReader(mOutputXmlString);
    using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader, lXmlReaderSettings))
    {
        addResponse = (AddResponseStructure)mDeserializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
        alertDetail = new AlertHostDetail(addResponse);
    }
}
catch
{
    _loggingManager.Log(LoggingHelpers.LoggingLevel.Error, "Error deserializing object.");
}
finally
{
    if (stringReader != null)
        stringReader.Dispose();
}
```

The warning is on the `stringReader.Dispose()` line.

Comment: When you exit the using statement the reader is automatically disposed.

Comment: Please have a look on https://stackoverflow.com/a/75483/2641352

Comment: To comment on the comment by @jdweng - both `xmlReader` and `stringReader` will be disposed of upon exiting the `using` statement block either normally or via a thrown exception.

Comment: @Rich Where `IDisposable`s are consumed by an `IDisposable` it's common in .Net that the consumed `IDisposable` is also disposed when the consumer is.

Comment: @phuzi To be clear, the double dispose is only because the `XmlReader` disposes the `StringReader`. The code shown here does not double dispose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code analysis warning is total baloney.  The [contract for `IDisposable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable.dispose#remarks) requires that extra calls to `Dispose` are accepted and do nothing (in particular, they should not throw `ObjectDisposedException` or any other exception).

> If an object's `Dispose` method is called more than once, the object must ignore all calls after the first one. **The object must not throw an exception if its `Dispose` method is called multiple times.** Instance methods other than `Dispose` can throw an `ObjectDisposedException` when resources are already disposed.

Source: [`IDisposable.Dispose` documentation on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable.dispose#remarks)

Unfortunately some framework code was written without reading the contract, and forbids calling Dispose more than once.  Those objects you should be careful not to double dispose.  But the universal contract is still that for an arbitrary `IDisposable`, calling `Dispose` multiple times is permitted.